# no matching function for call to std::vector<int>::erase(int&)

Tags: c++, vector

I have a problem with this snippet of code:

```
for(int i=n;i>0;i--)
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            if(docel[j]==docel[i])
                docel.erase(j);
```

Why is that that my program doesn't compile? I also tried:

```
docel.erase(docel.at(j))
```

Comment: [`std::vector::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) takes an iterator, not an index or a value.

Comment: Maybe read [some documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)?

Comment: Also, learn to use some [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) instead of re-inventing them

Answer (score 7):

`erase` takes an *iterator*, not an index value. A simple fix is to use `docel.erase(docel.begin() + j);`

But your code looks buggy on two counts:

1. Take care not to increment `j` if you erase the (j)th element though: you'll skip over values.
2. You'll also need to adjust `n` if the number of elements in `docel` is reduced.